# How to stop default function of keyboard key?

Tags: c#

I  made a `TextBox` and I bind <kbd>Space</kbd> to check if the string in `textbox1` and `richtextbox1` is the same:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
{
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(textBox1.Text))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text + " ", "");
        wpm++;
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

so I want when I press <kbd>Space</kbd> to **not** write space in `textbox1`

Comment: is there a problem with your code? do you have a question?

Comment: with this code no but i want idea how i can do that

Comment: e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

Comment: can you please state exactly what you are trying to do? Seems like you want the `Space` key to signify something when entered into a specific control. You posted some code, but you say there's nothing wrong with it. To me, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This answer adapted from the MSDN example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

```
// Boolean flag used to determine when a character other than a space is entered
private bool spaceEntered = false;

// Handle the KeyDown event to determine the type of character entered into the control.
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    spaceEntered = e.KeyCode == Keys.Space;
}

// This event occurs after the KeyDown event and can be used to prevent
// characters from entering the control.
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    if (spaceEntered == true)
    {
        // Stop the character from being entered into the control since 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Windows Forms, you can override any key behavior using the [Handled property of the event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).